# Spring taking String input from web page and converting into LocalDate conversion Error

Tags: spring-mvc

I am getting this error , can u please find what I am doing wrong.

> Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type
>   java.time.LocalDate' nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of  type
>   'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.time.LocalDate': no matching
>   editors  or conversion strategy found.

```
package com.pc.controller;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

@Controller
public class Controllera {

@RequestMapping(value="/home.htm",method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String showForm() {
    System.out.println("Controllera.showForm()");
    return "welcome";
}

@RequestMapping(value="/home.htm",method=RequestMethod.POST)    
public String process(Map<String ,Object>map,@RequestParam("date") 
                     @DateTimeFormat(pattern="dd-MM-yyyy") LocalDate date) {
    System.out.println("Controllera.process()");
    System.out.println(date);
    map.put("date",date);
    return "success";
}
}

//end of controller


My web page

<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<form method="POST">
<input type="text" name="date" id="date"/><br>
<input type="submit"/>
</form >
```

Comment: I'll suggest you to define the `date` parameter as a String and do the conversion inside the `process(...)` handler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Html default date format is YYYY-MM-YY.

You have 2 solutions for this:

1 - Change your parameter like `@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd") LocalDate date`

Also your controller method should be :

```
@RequestMapping(value="/home.htm",method=RequestMethod.POST)    
public String process(Map<String ,Object> map, @RequestParam("date") 
                     @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd") LocalDate date) {

// omitted for brevity.

 }
}
```

2 - Or you can do this in JSP for that you need to check [this](https://github.com/sargue/java-time-jsptags)

Comment: But i am recieving in dd-MM-yyyy pattern from user

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't understand. Is the solution solved your problem ?

Comment: and also there is no customPropertyEditor for java.time api. SO i think i have to work with java.util.date with @InitBinder